# UI component does not exist in current context when code moved to class from main UI thread

Tags: wpf, task-parallel-library

I currently have working code which is implemented in MainWindow.xaml.cs that I am trying to move to a class which is giving me an error that my UI label does not exist in the current context.

Here is the code that works in the MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
 ......
    private RX consumer = new RX();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        try
        {
            Task backgroundDBTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  { Consumer(consumer);}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }

   public void Consumer(Consumer consumer)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
             .......
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                mylbl.Content = value.ToString();
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
    }
```

Then I tried moving the code to a separate class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
 ....
    private RX consumer = new RX();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        try
        {
            Task backgroundDBTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { consumer.ProcessMessages(); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }

 }


public class RX
{

   public void ProcessMessages()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            ....

            var m_dispatcher = Application.Current.MainWindow;

            m_dispatcher.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                mylbl.Content = value.ToString();
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);

        }
    }

}
```

I'm getting the error on:

mylbl.Content = value.ToString();

from the class RX. I tried this as recommended var m_dispatcher = Application.Current.MainWindow to get to the MainWindow thread but its still giving an error.

Comment: `mylbl` is a member of the MainWindow class, which is accessible from the Consumer method in the same class, but obviously not from another class.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to make this work? I have seen a lot of posts using this: var m_dispatcher = Application.Current.MainWindow to get to the MainWindow thread but it still does not work. Or do I just keep the code on the MainWindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access mylbl from other classes , other than MyWindow since it is defined there . 
You can implement MVVM and bind the content property to string in view model and update the content .

or segregate your business logic to separate class and expose this to MyWindow.Xaml.cs.

You can have a public method which returns "value" in RX . and you can update your content in MyWindow.xaml.cs by accessing this method

or pass Label instance to ProcessMessage method and update the content. Of course,add a reference System.Windows.Controls in your class.

However this is not a good design . I suggest you to go through MVVM.

```
public void ProcessMessages(Label mylbl)
{

    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        ....

        var m_dispatcher = Application.Current.MainWindow;

        m_dispatcher.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            mylbl.Content = value.ToString();
        }), DispatcherPriority.Background);

    }
}
```

and caller will look like this

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
 ....
    private RX consumer = new RX();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        try
        {
            Task backgroundDBTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { consumer.ProcessMessages(mylbl); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }

 }
```

As suggested by Clemens , i am updating solution in MVVM way.
XAML Part:

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid >

        <Label Content="{Binding LableContent}" Height="100" Width="500" Foreground="Red"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

I am binding LableContent string property to Content property of Label. And setting data content at the top to my View Model. Also,to bind event to command i have used interactivity dll.

ViewModel will look like this.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Constants and Enums

    #endregion

    #region Private and Protected Member Variables 
    private string _lableContent;

    #endregion

    #region Private and Protected Methods
    private void OnLoaded(object obj)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ProcessMessages(); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public ViewModel()
    {
        LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(OnLoaded);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string LableContent
    {
        get
        {
            return _lableContent;
        }
        set
        {
            _lableContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LableContent));
        }
    }

    public ICommand LoadedCommand { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public void ProcessMessages()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            LableContent = "your value field";
        }
    }
    #endregion


}
```

I have used ICommand implementation for commands .
Also i have used INotifyPropertyChanged for binding .

I assume you have the knowledge about following topics , If not there are plenty of help available in stack overflow on these

1. INotifyProertyChanged
2. Event to command binding
3. What is data context and how to set the data context
4. what is ICommand and implementing ICommand

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to do the last suggestion. I think that will be the easiest way to accomplish this. Thank you.

Comment: I still have an error from mylbl.Content = value.ToString(); Plus I never return from ProcessMessages since its a while(true) loop. Its a listener.

Comment: ProcessMessages is a background Task called from ;

Comment: public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
 ....
    private RX consumer = new RX();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        try
        {
            Task backgroundDBTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { consumer.ProcessMessages(); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }

 }

Comment: Please pass a mylbl instance to ProcessMessages as shown in edited answer. And have Label control as parameter in your ProcessMessage method

Comment: Label mylbl = new Label();
            
            try
            {
                
                Task backgroundDBTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { consumer.ProcessMessages(mylbl); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }

Comment: ProcessMessage is accepting LABEL as parameter. Make corresponding change in ProcessMessage method as shown and Then pass your mylbl as parameter to this as shown in second block of code

Comment: Why are you creating new label . You should be able to access mylbl  as it is defined in xaml (i am assuming) . LABEL called "mylbl" is defined in XAML rgt?

Comment: Why don't you provide an example for the MVVM design, instead of showing what you call "not a good design"?

Comment: That would be great if you could provide a good example of this using MVVM. Is that possible? Otherwise the final suggested worked fine.

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much for your help.